# Difference between load and include in Scheme R7RS

Tags: scheme, lisp, r7rs

In Scheme R7RS there is both a `load` and `include` form.

Include is described as:

> Semantics: Both include and include-ci take one or
>   more filenames expressed as string literals, apply an
>   implementation-specific algorithm to find corresponding files, read
>   the contents of the files in the specified order as if by repeated
>   applications of read, and effectively re- place the include or
>   include-ci expression with a begin expression containing what was read
>   from the files. The difference between the two is that include-ci
>   reads each file as if it began with the #!fold-case directive, while
>   include does not. Note: Implementations are encouraged to search for
>   files in the directory which contains the including file, and to
>   provide a way for users to specify other directories to search.

Load is described as:

> An implementation-dependent operation is used to trans- form filename
>   into the name of an existing file con- taining Scheme source code. The
>   load procedure reads expressions and definitions from the file and
>   evalu- ates them sequentially in the environment specified by
>   environment-specifier. If environment-specifier is omitted,
>   (interaction-environment) is assumed. It is unspecified whether the
>   results of the expres- sions are printed. The load procedure does not
>   af- fect the values returned by current-input-port and
>   current-output-port. It returns an unspecified value. Rationale: For
>   portability, load must operate on source files. Its operation on other
>   kinds of files necessarily varies among implementations.

What is the rationale for the two forms? I assume it is historic. Is there any import semantic difference between the two forms? I see that `load` can optionally include an environment specifier and `include` doesn't have that. And `include-ci` has no direct equivalent using `load`. But comparing `load` and `include` alone, what is the difference and is it important?

Answer (score 5):

I think the critical difference is that `include` is *syntax* (or in traditional Lisp terms, it is a macro) while `load` is a function.  In traditional Lisp terms (there will be a much more formal definition of this in Scheme terms which I am not competent to give) this means that `include` does its work at macro-expansion time, while `load` does its work at evaluation time.  These times can be very different for an implementation which has a file compiler: macro-expansion time happens during compilation of files, while evaluation happens only much later, when the compiled files are loaded.

So, if we consider two files, `f1.scm` containing

```
(define foo 1)
(include "f2.scm")
```

and `f2.scm` containing

```
(define bar 2)
```

then if you load, *or compile* `f1.scm` it is exactly the same as if you had loaded or compiled a file `fe.scm` which contained:

```
(define foo 1)
(begin
  (define bar 2))
```

which in turn is the same as if `fe.scm` contained:

```
(define foo 1)
(define bar 2)
```

In particular this inclusion of the files happens at macro-expansion time, which happens when the compiler runs: the object file (fasl file) produced by the compiler will include compiled definitions of `foo` and `bar`, and will not in any way depend on `f2.scm` or its compiled equivalent existing.

Now consider `f3.scm` containing:

```
(define foo 1)
(load "f2")
```

(note I have assumed that `(load "f2")` (as opposed to `(load "f2.scm")`) loads the compiled file if it can find it, and the source file if it can't: I think this is implementation-dependent).

Loading the source of this file will do the same thing as loading `f1.scm`: it will cause `foo` and `bar` to be defined.  But *compiling* this file will not: it will produce a compiled file which, *when it is later loaded* will try to load either the source or compiled versions of `f2.scm`.  If that file exists, at load time, then it will be loaded and the effect will be the same as the `include` case.  If it does not exist at load time, bad things will happen.  Compiling `f1.scm` will not cause the definitions in `f2.scm` to be compiled.

---

Depending on your background it might be worth comparing this to, say, C-family languages.  What `include` does is what `#include` does: it splices in source files as they are read, and in C (as in many Scheme/Lisp systems) this happens as the files are compiled.  What `load` does is to load code *at runtime*, which, in C, you would need to do by invoking the dynamic linker or something.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, Lisp implementations did not offer module systems.

Large programs used **load** in order to run a set of instructions, the load function runs a **REPL script** by reading S-expressions from a file, one by one, and passing them to eval.

**Include**, on the other hand, is used to **inline the code read from a file** into the your code. It **does not evaluate the code.**

> ...replace the include or include-ci expression with a begin expression containing what was read from the files

**The added 'begin' prepares the code read from the file to be evaluated sequentially.**

Sources: Question quotes ,[Racket docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/load.html)